# Magento 2 - Layered navigation not shown if there is only category in categories filters

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation, filter, search-page

In `Search page`, when I query some string it does not show the layered navigation filters when resultant products set belong to one category. So I want to show that particular category in  categories filter because may be all products belong to one
category but they may belong to different sub categories and there is default pattern when you click on root category in categories filter it shows all subcategories in which resultant product set belongs.

The idea is to show either subcategories in category filter when there is one root category in which product belongs with already selected root category or just show that particular root category, when user click that particular root category it will show all related subcategory belongs to resultant products set.